# Filtering a multidimensional array

Tags: php, database

I have the following table in DB:

```
id | letter  
---|--------  
1  | A, B, C  
2  | D, E, F  
3  | A, C, E  
4  | B, D, F  
5  | G, I  
6  | H
```

The PHP code:

```
<?php

require_once './conn.php';

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT letter FROM letters ORDER BY letter ASC";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($res) === 0 || mysql_num_rows($res) === NULL) {
    echo '0 result(s)';
} else {
    // while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        echo $row['letter'] . ' / ';
    }
}

?>
```

Ok, I'll try to explain:
If I run the above code, it returns me A, B, C / D, E, F / A, C, E / B, D, F / G, I / H.
Each group of letters is an array, wow, I discovered the fire. Now the question:
How to put all the results into a single array and list so that the result is A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I?

Comment: I think you should modify your table structure, normalize, it's bad practice stored a matrix of data as you are doing, that's a relation many to many, and the tag more relevant in this case should be `sql` and the engine you'r using(mysql,SLQ-Server,oracle,etc) and what version

Comment: Responding to Mike Brant:
My intention is to list these values​​, for example, using "while" or "foreach".
So I wanted to unite all the values ​​in a single array to be able to list them.

Comment: I think this can be a good question, but I think we'd be more inclined to help if you'd show a bit of what you've already done. As is, there's not enough information to really help you: for example, we don't know what database engine (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.) you're using; we don't know what API (PDO, MySQLi, etc.) you're using. Showing some code might answer these questions and would show us that you've put some effort into it. If you edit your question to do that, it'll likely be reopened and someone might be able to help you out.

Comment: So your using DISTINCT to try and pull out individual letters. Problem is your are not storing then right. So you can use php to break up the results and then sort them or you can fix how your storing the data. Your choice. I suggest the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to the comments, using the `mysql` extension is strongly discouraged. It doesn't support prepared statements and you will write a SQL injection hole into your code without them. I know it's possible not to. Yet, most fall into it. Secure-by-default is always better.

Now, your wish, irregardless of whether it's a good idea or not:

```
$letters = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $letters = array_merge($letters, preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', trim($row['letter'])));
}
$letters = array_unique($letters);
sort($letters);
```

Comment: I am alert to safety, and I know that currently the PDO is the most suitable. I used the old mysql only to case study and agree that security is never enough.